# confused in switching from basic auth to oauth in twitter

Tags: php, oauth, twitter

I am using My Twitter library from Andrus Scheffer. Using this library , i am just   passing username and password to library file, and calling function was giving me proper results, but now as twitter has given deadline to turn off basic oauth.
     So I just need to switch to oauth. Currently i am hitting ratelimit status, userstatus, userfollowers and userclient urls. I am using php/mysql in my app.

I want to ask you guys that to hit above urls and get data from twitter API, which library should i go with including oauth. (i am really novice to oauth).

I am really confused on switching to oauth.

Answer (score 1):

I use [abraham's twitteroauth PHP library](http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) for my Twitter app; highly recommended.

You only need to include `OAuth.php` and `twitteroauth.php` in your script; the other files are for demonstration.